# MozRepl gives ReferenceError sometimes (BrowserReload())

Tags: mozrepl

I'm using MozRepl with Vim to reload the browser. This is the command I run:

```
echo "BrowserReload(); repl.quit()" | nc -w 1 localhost 4242
```

Sometimes it works, other times it gives `ReferenceError: BrowserReload is not defined`. Anybody in the know?

**EDIT**: OK, the problem is when the developer window is focused instead of the main window of Firefox.